# What are the AI and player modifiers for each difficulty level?

Tags: civilization-6

The major difference between each of the difficulty levels are the bonuses applied to the player and AI. These were [well known in Civ V](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_level_(Civ5)), but unsurprisingly it doesn't look like there's any hard data on Civ VI yet. I've tried looking through the various foldiers and files in `\Base\Assets` but haven't been able to find any hard numbers, although I know you could find that information in [the equivalent config files for Civ V](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/13672/8350).

What are the modifiers applied to the AI and player at each difficulty level?

Comment: Word of God says that they have a yield multiplier and nothing else in terms of units, but I have no hard evidence one way or the other.

Comment: [Looks like someone dug through the configs and found the answers. If someone doesn't get to it before me I plan to do some additional digging to confirm, and then compile it into an answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/59gkuk/civ_6_difficulty_scaling_and_tribal_village/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difficulty bonuses for Civ are described on [this](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Game_difficulty) wiki page. In general the game difficulty works such that

- Anything below prince gives you a bonus
- Prince gives no bonuses to anyone
- Above prince gives bonuses to the AI

I don't wan't to copy-paste all the values here (there are a lot), but I'll mention that the values being modified are:

- Science
- Culture
- Production
- Gold
- Faith
- Combat
- Research boosts
- Starting units
- Barbarian camp plunder yields

Comment: Oh excellent it's finally in the wiki.

Comment: No wonder deity is so hard. They start with 3 settlers, 2 builders, and 5 warriors on top of 5 science boosts and a myriad of other buffs.